# How to make client side click event handler to request a server side method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, event-handling

In details: I load HTML code onto the page and upon click of an `<a>` link, I want this click event to be captured and handled by the code-behind.

Here is what I've got as client-side code:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = { userName: $(this).attr("id") };
        var dataVal = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/loadNewPage",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataVal,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (id) {
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="kontakt">Go to Kontakt</a>
```

The problem is that the code-behind function is not called, but just the `#` is added to the url...

I'd much appreciate corrections on my code with code examples and maybe explanation on them.

**UPDATE:**
tried with ASP page webmethods. Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public string loadNewPage(string id)
{
    ltlContentCenter.Text = getPageCenter("kontakt");
    ltlContentSide.Text = getPageSide("kontakt");
    return "hello";
}
```

JS code:

```
function loadMe() {
        PageMethods.loadNewPage("kontakt", CallSuccess, CallError);
    }
    function CallSuccess(res) {
        alert(res);
    }
    function CallError() {
        alert('Error');
    }
```

the HTML:

```
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scpt" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
        <div id="parent">
        <div id="mainmenu">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="FORSIDEN" CommandArgument="forsiden" OnCommand="loadPage_Command"
                runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="PRODUKTER" CommandArgument="produkter" OnCommand="loadPage_Command"
                runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkPages" Text="SUPPORT" CommandArgument="media" OnCommand="loadPage_Command"
                runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" Text="KONTAKT" CommandArgument="kontakt" OnCommand="loadPage_Command"
                runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" Text="OM ABiX" CommandArgument="omabix" OnCommand="loadPage_Command"
                runat="server" />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
        </div>


        <asp:Literal ID="ltlContentCenter" runat="server" />
        <asp:Literal ID="ltlContentSide" runat="server" />
        <a href="#" onclick="loadMe()">Click Me, please.</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The browser console gives me error `"PageMethods is not defined"`.

Comment: `return false;` to prevent `<a>` tag from doing its default behavior

Answer (score 2):

Ok..not a jquery way but more of c# way to access server side using client script..Try using [page methods](http://codehandbook.org/an-asp-net-way-to-call-server-side-methods-using-javascript/)

First add a script manager on your aspx page

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scpt" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
</body>
```

Then go to your aspx.cs page and declare a function something like

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ValidateUser(string emailId, string password)
{
    //Your logic code
    return "hello from server side";
}
```

Then from your javascript call the c# method like

```
PageMethods.ValidateUser(email, password, CallSuccess_Login, CallFailed_Login);
```

And also in ur javascript create 2 call back functions CallSuccess_Login and CallFailed_Login

Hope it helps

Comment: @iBlue - hey. I did it this way. But the href of the <a> tag is with value # which means that when I click it - the only thing it is going to do is add the symbol "#" to the url and not execute the code-behind function. Any suggestions ?

Comment: can u put a break point in the server side code and check if its hitting.Just to check if the call is working

Comment: @iBlue - no, the call is not happening. It seems like the link is just blank. I Load the page and then even if I click - I am not taken to the function in debugging mode.

Comment: can u please update the FULL code dat you tried in question and also check if any error in browser console

Comment: @iBlue - I updated it. :) Btw, I have the same problem with the AJAX function. But lets focus on the ASP PageMethods approach for now.

Comment: Response.Redirect("TesdDevPage.aspx") is ur issue....its redirecting to another page and hence not returning the response to success callback

Comment: @iBlue - It doesn't seem to send my messages to you on the chat. Anyway, I used the `Response.Redirect` just for testing purposes. And yes - I am getting the `'hello'` message allert. So the problem must be in the code-behind method. How should I return the response in order for it to work. Because the purpose of my code-behind method is with `void` aims.

Comment: u getting any error in browser console???And plz update the code that u tried in your question.The present code doesn't return anything

Comment: @iBlue - I see. I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined `. I guess it is because of the `<asp:ScriptManager ID="scpt" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">`. I put it in the `<body> </body>`. Is that the right place ?

Comment: put it in inside a form tag inside body

Comment: @iBlue - But it is there: `<body onload="addEvents();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scpt" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" /> ...rest of the code...`

And the error is still thath `pagemethods` is not defined.

Comment: @iBlue - that is for another javascript function. It is irrelevant here.

Comment: @iBlue - I updated the HTML (without the scripts part in the head, because it's too long). And it is with the same problem, even after removing the `addEvents();`. Told you there's no relevance with this thing. 
Thanks for helping, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Use can do like this :

```
$('a').click(function () {

        var data = { userName: $(this).attr("id") };
        var dataVal = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/loadNewPage",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataVal,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (id) {
                alert("loaded");
            }
        });
    });

[WebMethod]
public static void loadNewPage(int id)
{
  // do the loading of the new HTML, etc.  
}
```

You can know more about Jquery AJAX call over [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: This is my HTML: `<a href="#" id="kontakt">Go to Kontakt</a>` and I added `$('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault;` so it doesn't just open `#` but it still does. Any idea ? (because the function apparently is not doing what it should)

If I do it `href="javascript:: void(0)"` the function doesn't work again.

Comment: @Syspect - I am unable to understand what you mean in the above line.

Comment: the `href` of the `<a>` tag is with value `#` which means that when I click it - the only thing it is going to do is add the symbol "#" to the url and not execute the jQuery function. That is why I added to the function `event.preventDefault()` so it doesn't do that but instead - execute the function, but it still does the default `#` thing. So any ideas why it is like that ?

Comment: @Syspect - event.preventDefault() is used to prevent the page post back on click of <a> tag. The href will come in your url, whenever you click the <a> tag, you can replace the '#' with 'kontakt'.

Comment: If I replace the "#" with "kontakt" then it will redirect me to page "kontakt" and there is no such page in the project. But that's not important. The important thing is that the AJAX function still doesn't execute.